# How correctly improve this piece of PHP code to follow DRY?

Tags: php, angularjs

I know that my question is plain, but I'm stucked and have no one to ask, but wanna do it right. Now my code works properly, but it's obviously not follow DRY so I'm asking for help. *Current* code:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$answer_1 = $request->answer_1;
$answer_2 = $request->answer_2;
$answerUser = $request->answerUser;

$answer_1  = pathinfo($answer_1, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$answer_2  = pathinfo($answer_2, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

$filename = 'answers/' . $answer_1 . '.txt';
$f = fopen($filename, 'r+');
  if ($f) {
     $size = filesize($filename);
     $content_1 = fread($f, $size);
     $content_1 = trim($content_1);
     fclose($f);
  }
$filename = 'answers/' . $answer_2 . '.txt';
$f = fopen($filename, 'r+');
  if ($f) {
    $size = filesize($filename);
    $content_2 = fread($f, $size);
    $content_2 = trim($content_2);
    fclose($f);
}

if (strcmp($content_1, $answerUser) == 0 || strcmp($content_2, $answerUser) == 0) {
  http_response_code(200);
} else {
  http_response_code(400);
}
```

My code **works fine,** there is no errors, but I dunno how to do correctly refactoring here.
So, now if ( just for example ) I got 20 '*answers*' from client I have to write almost identical 20 expressions, but apparently it has to be a function. Any advises will be greatly ... you know :)

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. What is the expected input? What does `answers/answer_1.txt` look like? What does `$request` look like?

Comment: You could do a [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) on the $request object. In the loop do your 4 lines of code. If you need an example I can post one.

Comment: Also is there any reason you did `file_get_contents("php://input");` instead of just using `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: @mister martin .txt contains just a string with correct answer. In $request I get object that contains something like {"answer_1":"test_1/5anhasf100.mp3","answer_2":"test_2/jk4b8j0k1l.jpg","answerUser":"jgrhgradhrdashyekj"}

Comment: @Austin Schmidt I can't use just $_REQUEST, it's Angular, not jQuery.

Comment: @impregnablefiend AngularJS exists only on the client side, you can implement server logic in any way you desire. Did you need an example or do you understand how to implement this code with `foreach` statement?

Comment: @Austin Schmidt I mean that Angular returns JSON, so I have to do it in that way. And, like I said, my code works fine, I just dunno how correctly refactoring it. If you can provide example I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work fine. The important thing is that you check at the start of the foreach loop whether the element is actually an answer or something else. I'll leave that part to you since you know the details of the data input better.

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
$answerUser = $request->answerUser;

$any_correct = false;

foreach ($request as $answer) {
    //Implement some logic right here to check whether it is an answer or not!
    if($answer){
        $path = pathinfo($answer, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
        $filename = 'answers/' . $path . '.txt';
        $f = fopen($filename, 'r+');
        if ($f) {
            $size = filesize($filename);
            $content_1 = fread($f, $size);
            $content_1 = trim($content_1);
            fclose($f);

            if(strcmp($content_1, $answerUser) == 0){
                $any_correct = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
if($any_correct){
    http_response_code(200);
}else{
    http_response_code(400);
}
```